# Python: "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly" x "arguments (" y " given)"; x>0<y

Tags: python, polymorphism, overloading

The type error happened to me when assuming one language's concepts, specifically C++/Java/etc.'s "Function Overloading" [1] of parameters, works in another, Python in this case. My conclusion likely needs review, and could be more detailed with someone that knows Python's source code, but I believe it is generally a good assessment and advice.

### Experiment

**Code 1:**

```
class Toolbox:    
  trayA = ()    
  trayB = ()    

  def __init__(self):
        self.trayA = ("nail", "screw")        
        self.trayB = ("hammer", "nail", "long nail")

  def __init__(self,tA,tB):
        self.trayA = tA
        self.trayB = tB

#Instance defs
tb = Toolbox()
#tb = Toolbox(("n1","n2","n5"),("screwdriver","long screw"))

#Test
print(tb.trayA)
print(tb.trayB)
```

**Result:** 
"TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"
**Analysis:** 
*The number of parameters expected, 3, matches the second init definition of the 2 defined.
*The definition used was the second of the 2 defined.

**Code 2:**
**Description:**
 
From Code 1, removed the comment on the 3-param call.
Commented out the 1-param call.
**Result:** 
pass (i.e. no error)

**Code 3:**
**Description:**
 
From Code 1, switched order of init definitions.
**Result:** 
pass

**Code 4:**
**Description:**
 
From Code 3, commented out the 1-param call, and uncommented the 3-param call
**Result:** 
Fail "TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)"

### Conclusion:

The last defined function/method of a sequence of overloaded functions/methods, is the only definition Python refers to when a programmer is defining/calling an instance of those functions/methods.

### Acknowledgement

I believe it is important to be specific when the audience is a technical one, the author is knowledgeable enough, and there is enough time to consider the conditions for specifics (if not strong enough in a concept to immediately use the term). Thank you Paul Rooney for helping me be more specific, using "Function Overloading"[1] in place of "Polymorphism"[2,3], especially after I use the term, "specifically".

### Reference

[1]: "Function overloading". Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading. Accessed 9/20/2017.
[2]: Cohoon & Davidson. C++ Program Design. 3rd ed. 2002. 
[3]: "Polymorphism (computer science)". Wikipedia. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science). Accessed 9/20/2017.

Comment: Defining `__init__()` multiple times does **not** create different versions of it.  Each subsequent definition _replaces_ the previous one.  If you want a function to accept varying numbers of arguments, use `*args` and/or `**kwargs`.

Comment: The only one way to solving your issue is to use default parameters or `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: I think you are mistaking the concept of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) for the concept of [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). They are not the same. Python has no notion of overloading. The constructor function must inspect their arguments to decide upon how to configure the object.

Comment: I was using Polymorphism as a general term that included function overloading, operator overloading, inheritance, etc. Function Overloading, where the functions with the same names do different things depending on the parameter list types and number of parameters, is more specific, but I don't think using the term Polymorphism is wrong. I think of Polymorphism as the ability of same-named code to act differently due to code somehow attached to it.

Comment: I checked an old [intro programming textbook][1]. It said, "function and operator overloading" are "primitive forms of polymorphism" [1]. The Wikipedia reference you provided on Polymorphism seems to me to have a subclass, ["ad hoc polymorphism"][2] as an intermediate term between yours and mine [2]. [1]: Cohoon & Davidson. C++ Program Design. 3rd ed. 2002. [2]: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: ok I retract my comment about polymorphism and function overloading being not the same. It says it right there on the page (blush). I suppose polymorphism is a more nuanced and generalized beast than I had though.

Answer (score 0):

if there are more than one function with the same name, python use the last one.
pythonic way to make different constructors is like:

```
class Toolbox:
    def __init__(self, tA=None, tB=None):
        if not tA:
            tA = ("nail", "screw")

        if not tB:
            tB = ("hammer", "nail", "long nail")

        self.trayA = tA
        self.trayB = tB

    def __str__(self):
        return "trayA=%s, trayB=%s" % (self.trayA, self.trayB)


a = Toolbox()
b = Toolbox(('bolt', 'nut'))
c = Toolbox(('bolt', 'nut'), ('saw', 'chisel'))


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

**output**

```
trayA=('nail', 'screw'), trayB=('hammer', 'nail', 'long nail')
trayA=('bolt', 'nut'), trayB=('hammer', 'nail', 'long nail')
trayA=('bolt', 'nut'), trayB=('saw', 'chisel')
```

python use this method for python `type()` too.
u can check the type of a variable:

```
>>> x="str"
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

or u can make a class with it.

```
class A:
    pass
x = A()
print(type(x))
```

is equal with :

```
A = type("A", (), {})
x = A()
print(type(x))
```

Comment: made it. is it okay ?

Comment: really nice  style

Comment: @PaulRooney I am going to update the code with yours

Comment: No probs. as long as you understand the change.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your tips.
Based on the advice provided earlier by John Gordon and AndMar to use *argv, I revised the code to handle multiple parameter inputs.

```
class Toolbox:
trayA = ()
trayB = ()
def __init__(self,*argv):
    if len(argv) == 2:
        self.trayA = argv[0]
        self.trayB = argv[1]
    else:
        self.trayA = ("nail", "screw")
        self.trayB = ("hammer", "nail", "long nail")
def printContents(self,a):
    print("Init Arguments Count Used = ",a)
    print(self.trayA)
    print(self.trayB)
    print("")


#Initialize and Print
tb = Toolbox()
tb.printContents(0)

tb = Toolbox(("n1","n2","n5"),("screwdriver","long screw"))
tb.printContents(2)

tb = Toolbox(("n1","n2","n5"),("screwdriver","long screw"),("n3","n7","drill bit"))
tb.printContents(3)
```

### Result

```
('Init Arguments Count Used = ', 0)
('nail', 'screw')
('hammer', 'nail', 'long nail')

('Init Arguments Count Used = ', 2)
('n1', 'n2', 'n5')
('screwdriver', 'long screw')

('Init Arguments Count Used = ', 3)
('nail', 'screw')
('hammer', 'nail', 'long nail')
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it doesn't check for undesired argument counts, nor argument types. Paul Rooney was solving the type problem. The count problem could be solved with another condition for the default, len(argv) == 0, case, and the else could just print("Error! Wrong argument list called") or throw an exception of some sort.